# plotting a graph and finding the error(its more software and less electronics)

Tags: graph

I have found an output for a RC circuit from ltspice and then tried  predicting it using matlab. I converted both the data into text form and observed them by plotting. I want to find the maximum and average error ,  but number of points are different for the outputs (for ltspice is 635 and matlab is 747), so simple excel subtraction wont work. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Interpolate the two sets of data onto the same time points. Do this in Matlab. (You have Matlab in front of you, why are you even considering touching Excel?)

Comment: Make sure you have `.opt plotwinsize=0` before exporting -- it disables waveform compression.